# Box2DWeb b2EdgeShape

Tags: javascript, box2d, box2dweb

How to make a b2EdgeShape? Making a simple b2EdgeShape. Simple boilerplate b2EdgeShape to build on top of.

My code:

```
var bodyDef = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef;
bodyDef.type = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body.b2_staticBody;
bodyDef.position.SetV(new Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2(250/30, 250/30));

var fixtureDef = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = new Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2EdgeShape(
  new Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2(2.5,0), 
  new Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2(2.5,2.5));

fixtureDef.density = 0;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.0;

var body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
var fixture = body.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to use **b2EdgeShape** yet. It is not fully implemented in box2dweb.

Instead of **b2EdgeShape** you can use **b2PolygonShape** as follows:

```
fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape()
fixDef.shape.SetAsEdge(new b2Vec2(x1, y1), new b2Vec2(x2, y2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Podgorskiy. If you can put in a codepen or  js fiddle of this, that'll be great.